# SimpleDateFormater returning null for MMM d yyyy h:mm a pattern

Tags: java, simpledateformat, datetime-format

I am not able to parse date successfully. Here is the code snippet.

input string :  May 9 2013 8:29 AM

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d yyyy h:mm a", Locale.US);'

dateFormater.parse(dateString)";
```

I am not getting any exceptions also. Could you help me in resolving this?

The parser always returns null. I read documentation and it says if there is any exception the parse would eventually gives null.

I will try different options and post an answer for this.

Comment: There is something else going on here. Please paste the full relevant code.

Comment: Your code snippet is good with the input string you have mentioned.

Comment: What kind of output pattern would u expect to get?

Comment: it isn't returning null, you just didn't print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just figured out that the web service which am accessing is returning an extra space like this -->

" May 9 2013 8:29 AM".

As a result the parse method is not able to parse the string successfully.

I used String's trim method to remove white spaces before and after the date string.

Now am able to parse the date string into date.

Thanks a lot for your support. I didn't realize that white spaces also causes an issue.

Now everything looks ok. The way I implemented is correct only but in addition to that i need to make sure that the string dont have white spaces before and after, 
since I defined the pattern as --> 
"MMM d yyyy h:mm a" which don't have white space.

Another way to fix it is--> instead of using trim to avoid white spaces... 
I can make the pattern as --> 
" MMM d yyyy h:mm a" (note there is a white space at starting)

Answer (score 1):

```
    String dateString = "May 9 2013 8:29 AM";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d yyyy h:mm a", Locale.US);
    Date date = dateFormater.parse(dateString);
    System.out.print(date);
```

Just worked fine for me...